# C# Selenium entrar em menu

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando o acesso a um site, ele abre navegador, faz o login, vai até uma certa página e após isso, aparece uma lista suspensa para escolher a "Categoria"
Dentro desta lista suspensa, tenho 3 itens apenas, ele chega a abrir a lista suspensa mais não clica ou entra.

```
        public void DropDown()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).Click();
    }
```

Já tentei com Name, TagName, Value, Id, Class, sem sucesso.

```
<table class="MenuTable" style="width: 123px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody class="MenuTableBody"><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryNameHover" nowrap="">Criado por Mim</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSubHover" arvalue="Criado por Mim"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Todos os Relatórios</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Todos os Relatórios"></td></tr><tr class="MenuTableRow"><td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">(Limpar)</td><td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue=""></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

e o XPath que tenho quando, detalhe sou novato em programação e ainda não sei muita coisa sobre XPath

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

Este valor é me passado pelo Navegador copiando XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim.

```
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("selection")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("arid_WIN_0_93210")).SendKeys(Keys.Down);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("arid_WIN_0_93210")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```